# How can I get how many are clients subscribing a Streaming PushTopic via Apex?

Tags: apex, streaming-api

I want to know how many are clients subscribing a Streaming PushTopic via Apex, but I can't find the solution in the Streaming and Apex documents, anyone know this? Thanks.